# Laravel 5.7, Blank page on redirect

Tags: php, laravel, paypal-sandbox, laravel-5.7

I am developing an app that uses PayPal checkout, the problem is that when I hit the **try** on **getExpressCheckout** function, I got a blank page when I am returning a **redirect** to a PayPal process payment URL.

I try to redirect from another function to see if the problem was globally, but the redirect works with a hardcoded URL, I tried `Redirect::to()` with no success.

This is my code ...

```
public function getExpressCheckout()
    {
        $options = [
            'BRANDNAME' => 'Cubik',
            'LOGOIMG' => 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
            'CHANNELTYPE' => 'Merchant'
        ];

        $recurring = true;
        $cart = $this->getCheckoutData($recurring);

        try {
            $response = $this->provider->addOptions($options)->setExpressCheckout($cart, $recurring);
            return redirect($response['paypal_link']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->with("danger",__('Error processing PayPal payment!'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is APP_DEBUG = true in your .env file ? If not then please make it true and then check error and post it here.

Comment: `dd($e->getMessage())` to see the exception on catch section

Comment: Open your browsers developer tools and keep the log running between requests and check if the redirect page is the correct page you'd expect.

Comment: The app have the debug **on** in the **.env**, the funny thing is that the function does not hit the **catch**

Comment: I found the issue, the **return** was missing in the function calling **getExpressCheckout**

Fixed from this:

**$this->getExpressCheckout($request);**

to this:

** return $this->getExpressCheckout($request);**